# Generate a key that is consistent over time

Tags: java, cryptography

I am trying to [generate a key](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/Key.html) and it is important that each time the class is run, the key be exactly the same.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The documentation you linked to is outdated: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html Also the Java tutorials have a decent explanation of key generation and digital signatures: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/step2.html

Comment: What do you need it for? I ask because the idea behind key-generation is exactly the opposite: that the generator should never generate the same key twice. Maybe you're trying to solve the wrong problem?

Comment: I am trying to encrypt a save file for a game, using the Cypher class, which takes a key. The data needs to be encrypted, and then saved to a file. When the user restarts the game, the file will need to be decrypted, (using the same key).

Comment: This depends on what kind of key, You could use Diffie-Hellman to derive the same key each time and use that as the encryption key

Comment: Where are you planning to store your key? You cannot generate a key out of thin air. You could store the key with your application data (which amounts to obfuscation) or ask the user for a password.

Answer (score 1):

As said in your link, a Key is produced by an encryption algorithm (RSA, DSA).  Java ships with [several different algorithms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyFactory), which can be used by a [KeyFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html) to produce keys.  I'm confused by your desire to recreate the same key multiple times.  Typically you create a key once, and then store its encoded form.  You can recreate the key from the encoded form in the future.

---

Edit:
I understand your problem better now.  I thought you wanted a key pair for public/private encryption.  For saving a game, a symmetric key is good enough.  Note that this "good enough" example takes a lot of shortcuts.  *Any* symmetric key algorithm can be cracked if the code is executed on a client, and this is no different.  But for a game, this will prevent 99.9% of users from decrypting save states.

```
// I use String.getBytes() as a convenince a lot.  I specify the encoding
// to ensure that the result is consistent.
final String utf8 = "utf-8";

String password = "It's a secret!  Make sure it's long enough (24 bytes)";
byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(password.getBytes(utf8), 24);
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");

// Your vector must be 8 bytes long
String vector = "ABCD1234";
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(vector.getBytes(utf8));

// Make an encrypter
Cipher encrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

// Make a decrypter
Cipher decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

// Example use
String message = "message";
byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes(utf8);
byte[] encryptedByted = encrypt.doFinal(messageBytes);
byte[] decryptedBytes = decrypt.doFinal(encryptedByted);

// You can re-run the exmaple to see taht the encrypted bytes are consistent
System.out.println(new String(messageBytes, utf8));
System.out.println(new String(encryptedByted, utf8));
System.out.println(new String(decryptedBytes, utf8));
```

Comment: How could I store it's encoded form and then recreate the key from that encoded form then?

Comment: No, it's not perfect. It restricts the key to the UTF-8 range of the input characters. It does not even change the key if you change the last part (over 24 bytes) of the password. Strings should not be used as keys; use PBKDF2 to go from a password to a key. The IV is also depending on the UTF-8 encoding the input string. If a character takes more than one byte, then the method will fail.